# Viewing the Full Container Frame of the Mobile Website in Chrome Browser Emulation

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, mobile-website

I will try my best to explain. I am using my Chrome browser to emulate iPhone 5 and look at different websites. The website displays in a frame which corresponds to the iPhone 5 frame as shown below:

[image]

This all works but I want to see the scrollable content too without scrolling. In other words I am interested in taking a single screenshot of the complete page without scrolling.  Is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: For people voting to close this question. Where should I post it and whom should I ask?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't iPhone specific, but Google's PageSpeed API offers the ability to view a screenshot of a particular live website in "mobile" and "desktop" mode. It's not an exact indication for a particular device, but it's handy to get a general feel for how a website shapes up on mobile and also handy if you are looking at many websites.

I needed this for something I'm working on and wrote a plunk using Angular here: http://plnkr.co/edit/c7fAFx?p=preview. In the end it's just making the following GET call, and using slightly modified results to display an image.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=<your-website-url>&key=<your-api-key>&screenshot=true&strategy=<mobile OR desktop>
```

You'll need to register a Google API account and grant it access to the PageSpeed API. Not sure if it's what you are after, but might help.